# Convert DateTime to string using another string as a template

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a string that contains a date & time in some format. For example:

```
13:53:56 20.08.2014
```

This string is parsed from a file that user uploads to my service. The exact date & time format is not known. It can change to pretty much any date & time format you know. I do not have a list a expected formats or anything like that.

I want to develop an algorithm that somehow extracts the format from the initial string and applies it to, say, `DateTime.Now`.
Is there any way to do this simply and elegantly?

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is your friend here.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out the string formatting and then apply the same rules to a different `DateTime`?

Comment: @ryanyuyu. Yes. I've corrected my question to be more accurate

Comment: You say that formats can change how many formats are there? With dates you need to be exact as swapping month and day can change the date a lot. Where is the date time string coming from? local workstation? web service? give us a bit more detail as there could be better answers.

Comment: Here is a simple suggestion, the user that uploads the file can also upload its region settings for the date and time with the file, you can use this information to parse the date time from the file.

Comment: What format would you infer from the date `02-03-04` ?

Comment: Is this a web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by a good suggestion by Mani, I've created the following extension method for my needs:

```
public static bool TryFormatLike(this DateTime dateTime, string another, out string result)
{
    var allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures | CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture | CultureTypes.ReplacementCultures);
    foreach (var culture in allCultures)
    {
        var allPatterns = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();
        foreach (var pattern in allPatterns)
        {
            DateTime parsedAnother;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(another, pattern, culture.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out parsedAnother))
            {
                result = dateTime.ToString(pattern);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    result = string.Empty;
    return false;
}
```

You can use it like that:

```
string formattedNow;
if (DateTime.Now.TryFormatLike("13.02.2015 16:14:43", out formattedNow))
{
    Console.WriteLine(formattedNow);
}
```

This will print

```
10.03.2015 23:37:08
```

Unfortunately, some date & time formats cannot be parsed by all patters in all cultures (for instance, string `16:14:43 13.02.2015` will not be parsed).

Anyway, thank you for your comments & answers. Maybe this method will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the list of expected formats, then define them and use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` to find out the matching format of your input string. Once you have the matching format, you can simply use the matching format with `DateTime.Now.ToString(format)`.

Comment: "If you know the list of expected formats" - that's the trick, I do not know the list of expected formats.

Comment: Sorry if this is not helpful but you need to find a way to identify the format from the input string, other wise you simple don't know whether 53:56 is mm:ss or ss:mm :). The problem you are trying to solve is similar to creating regex pattern from the matching strings which we know isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a web application, perhaps you can "cheat a bit" by sniffing the user's regional settings before they input the string.

The MSDN article "[How to: Display Localized Date and Time Information to Web Users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882561%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)" has useful information.